# Pull a separate column that matches the (min) of an aggregate function

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions, partition, row-number

It works well so far but I am stumped from here as I am brand new to this. This query finds the closest distance match, pairing up every item in the "FAILED" folder against everything that isn't in the "FAILED" folder.

There is a column "RouteID" in the "table p" that I want to match up with the min() aggregate.

I cannot process how to make the SELECT query simply show the associated "RouteID" column from tbl p but ultimately, I want to turn this into an update query that will SET a.Route = p.Route that is associated with the min()

Any help would be appreciated.

```
SELECT a.name, a.Reference1,
    MIN(round(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(90-a.lat))
     *COS(RADIANS(90-p.latpoint))
     +SIN(RADIANS(90-a.lat))
     *SIN(RADIANS(90-p.latpoint))
     *COS(RADIANS(a.lon-p.longpoint)))
     *3958.756,2)) AS 'DISTANCE'

FROM tblOrder AS a WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN 
     (
         SELECT b.lat AS latpoint, b.lon AS longpoint,
             b.Sequence, b.routeid
             from tblOrder b WITH (NOLOCK)
              WHERE b.CUSTID = 180016
              AND b.routeID <> 'FAILED'
              AND b.StopType = 1
     ) AS p ON 1=1

WHERE a.CustID = 180016
AND a.RouteID = 'FAILED'
AND a.StopType = 1
AND P.RouteID <> 'FAILED'

GROUP BY
a.name, a.Reference1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select them separately and then join them

```
SELECT c.name, c.Reference1, q.RouteID
FROM 
(
   SELECT a.name, a.Reference1,
   MIN(round(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(90-a.lat))
   *COS(RADIANS(90-p.latpoint))
   +SIN(RADIANS(90-a.lat))
   *SIN(RADIANS(90-p.latpoint))
   *COS(RADIANS(a.lon-p.longpoint)))
   *3958.756,2)) AS 'DISTANCE'

  FROM tblOrder AS a WITH (NOLOCK)
  LEFT JOIN 
  (
     SELECT b.lat AS latpoint, b.lon AS longpoint,
         b.Sequence, b.routeid
         from tblOrder b WITH (NOLOCK)
          WHERE b.CUSTID = 180016
          AND b.routeID <> 'FAILED'
          AND b.StopType = 1
  ) AS p ON 1=1

 WHERE a.CustID = 180016
 AND a.RouteID = 'FAILED'
 AND a.StopType = 1
 AND P.RouteID <> 'FAILED'
 GROUP BY
 a.name, a.Reference1
 ) c
 LEFT JOIN 
 (
     SELECT b.lat AS latpoint, b.lon AS longpoint,
         b.Sequence, b.routeid
         from tblOrderRouteStops b WITH (NOLOCK)
          WHERE b.CUSTID = 180016
          AND b.routeID <> 'FAILED'
          AND b.StopType = 1
 ) AS q 
 ON q.routeID = c.DISTANCE
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have been attempting this but I am stuck on this- how can I reference tbl p in the subquery to pull p.longpoint and p.latpoint?

Comment: i think in that case you would have to join the table again. Check the modified answer

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. No errors but unfortunately the query generates no results. I have not yet determined why but there must be something contradictory. I will check it out and let you know, thank you again